# Поддерживают ли стандартные потоки C++ полиморфное использование?

Tags: c++, fstream

Скажите, пожалуйста, поддерживают ли стандартные потоки `C++` полиморфное использование?

Например:

```
void Function(std::ifstream& ifstream)
{
    // ...
}

std::fstream fstream;
Function(fstream);
```

Я пытался найти внятный ответ, но не смог. Попробовал выяснить сам, полистав исходный код `stl`, но там ничего не понятно.

Comment: Почему было не заглянуть в документацию?

Comment: и прям там https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream видно, что одно есть наследником другого...

Comment: @KoVadim что-то не видно там связи `ifstream` и `fstream`.

Comment: @KoVadim, правильно ли я вас понимаю, что вы утверждаете, что если `B` наследуется от `A`, - это гарантия того, что `B` всегда может быть корректно использован через ссылку/указатель на `A`?

Comment: нет, не утверждаю. Программист может сделать все что угодно. Но в общем случае, работает. Это как бы принцип Лисков

Comment: Меня интересует не общий случай, а то, дает ли документация гарантию. Я не вижу в документации ни слова об этом. И в исходном коде я тоже не вижу никаких признаков ответа на мой вопрос.

Comment: Это основи ООП в с++. Да, в общем случае можно подсовывать дочерний класс там, где ожидается родительский. Если хотите гарантий - это к Страуструпу. Но если бы этих гарантий не было, то почти ничего бы не работало/не компилировалось

Comment: EOF правильно подсказывает, что ifstream не есть предком fstream, поэтому конкретний пример работать не будет. Но если использовать istream (который есть предком fstream) вместо ifstream, то все будет работать.

Answer (score 3):

Известно, что ссылка на базовый класс может ссылаться на объект производного класса (в данном случае имеется ввиду `public` наследование) без явного преобразования.
Теперь давайте взглянем на иерархию классов ввода-вывода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Видим, что `basic_fstream` наследуется от `basic_iostream`, который наследуется от двух классов: `basic_istream` и `basic_ostream`. А класс `basic_ifstream` наследуется от `basic_istream`. Т.е. `basic_fstream` и `basic_ifstream` имеют ближайшего общего предка `basic_istream`. Тогда Ваша функция должна иметь вид

```
void Function(std::istream& stream) // для char, или wistream для wchar_t
{
    // ...
}
```

чтобы принимать объекты классов `ifstream` и `fstream`. Но, имеет ли это смысл? Это уже другой вопрос.